# Assume $AX = C$. How to determine which entry of $BX - D$ is non-negative?

Tags: matrix, algorithms, reference-request, matrix-equations

Let $A,B$ be $n \times n$ matrices and $C,D$ be $n \times 1$ matrices. Moreover, all entries of $A,B,C,D$ are non-negative. Assume that there is a unique matrix $X$ that solves $AX = C$.

My goal is not to calculate $X$, but to determine which entry of $BX - D$ is non-negative. In solving my problem, I need to repeat this procedure several times.

I would like to ask if there is an efficient method (or references) to do so. Thank you so much!

Comment: Make your life easier and call vectors "vectors" rather than "$n\times 1$ matrices" :-)

Comment: Hi @WolfgangBangerth, I've just posted the refinement of this question [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3696623/how-to-utilize-the-special-feature-of-this-recursive-problem-to-reduce-computati). Because this is an essential part of my thesis, I hope that you have a look at it and lend me some suggestion ^_^

Comment: I have no idea about what can or can not be shown in this area.

Comment: Thank you for your response @WolfgangBangerth ^^